# Searching anagrams with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, anagram

I have to write program which should be reading file for anagrams and show word + his anagrams. Txt files is very big, after using scanner, listOfWords size is: 25000.

Output example:

```
word anagram1 anagram2 anagram3 ...
word2 anagram1 anagram2...
```

I have code, it works but very slow:

```
  private static List<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static List<ArrayList<String>> allAnagrams = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("www.xxx.pl/textFile.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      String nextToken = scanner.next();
      listOfWords.add(nextToken);
    }
    scanner.close();

    while (listOfWords.isEmpty() == false) {
      ArrayList<String> anagramy = new ArrayList<String>();
      String wzor = listOfWords.remove(0);
      anagramy.add(wzor);
      char[] ch = wzor.toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(ch);
      for (int i = 0; i < listOfWords.size(); i++) {
        String slowo = listOfWords.get(i);
        char[] cha = slowo.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(cha);
        if (Arrays.equals(ch, cha)) {
          anagramy.add(slowo);
          listOfWords.remove(i);
          i--;
        }
      }
      allAnagrams.add(anagramy);
    }

    for (ArrayList<String> ar : allAnagrams) {
      String result = "";
      if (ar.size() > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < ar.size(); i++) {
          result = ar.get(i) + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(ar.get(0) + " " + result);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have to write it with Java 8 - streams but I don't know. It is possible to use Streams for reading from URL + searching anagrams? Could you help me with searching anagrams by Stream? Teacher told me that code should be shorter that mine with reading a whole list. Only a few lines, is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can read the words from the file into a List or directly create a Stream of it:

```
try (InputStream is = new URL("http://www.someurl.pl/file.txt").openConnection().getInputStream();
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     Stream<String> stream = reader.lines()) {
       //do something with stream
}
```

Then just stream over the list and collect the anagrams, where all words that have the same sorted list of characters are considered anagrams:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams =
    stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> sorted(w)));
```

The sorted method is just sorting the letters as you did in your example:

```
public static String sorted(String word) {
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's create separate method which sorts letters. You can do this with Stream API as well:

```
private static String canonicalize(String s) {
    return Stream.of(s.split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Now you can read some `Reader`, extract words from it and group words by canonical form:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new BufferedReader(reader).lines()
             .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\W+")::splitAsStream)
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Anagrams::canonicalize, Collectors.toSet()));
```

Next, you can remove single letter groups using Stream API for the third time:

```
return map.values().stream().filter(list -> list.size() > 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you can pass some reader to this code to extract anagrams from it. Here's complete code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Anagrams {
    private static String canonicalize(String s) {
        return Stream.of(s.split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    public static List<Set<String>> getAnagrams(Reader reader) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new BufferedReader(reader).lines()
                                     .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\W+")::splitAsStream)
                                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Anagrams::canonicalize, Collectors.toSet()));
        return map.values().stream().filter(list -> list.size() > 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        getAnagrams(new StringReader("abc cab tat aaa\natt tat bbb"))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

It prints

```
[att, tat]
[abc, cab]
```

If you want to use an URL, just replace the `StringReader` with `new InputStreamReader(new URL("www.xxx.pl/textFile.txt").openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

---

If you want to extract the first element of the anagram set, the solution should be modified slightly:

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> getAnagrams(Reader reader) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new BufferedReader(reader).lines()
       .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\W+")::splitAsStream)
       .distinct() // remove repeating words
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Anagrams::canonicalize));
    return map.values().stream()
       .filter(list -> list.size() > 1)
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(list -> list.get(0), 
                                 list -> new TreeSet<>(list.subList(1, list.size()))));
}
```

Here the result is the map where the key is the first element in anagram set (first occurred in the input file) and the value is the rest elements sorted alphabetically (I make a sublist to skip the first element, then move them into `TreeSet` to perform sorting; an alternative would be `list.stream().skip(1).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())`).

Example usage:

```
getAnagrams(new StringReader("abc cab tat aaa\natt tat bbb\ntta\ncabr\nrbac cab crab cabrc cabr"))
        .entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Really? `Stream.of(s.split(""))`? Despite you’re using `Pattern.splitAsStream` within the same answer? Not to speak of the *much* more efficient `s.codePoints().sorted() .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();`. Though using a `char[] a=s.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(a); return String.valueOf(a);` might be the simpler choice here.

Comment: Good job, could you tell me where can I add my own sort implementation which would be sorting anagrams (without first word)?

Comment: @Holger, nobody asked the most efficient solution, only Stream API based solution was requested. If you have performance problems here, you should not use streams in the first place (btw, in this case using `CharBuffer.wrap(a)` as key is probably more efficient). If you just want the Stream API, then my solution is definitely shorter and easier to understand than your alternatives.

Comment: I don’t believe that you are serious with “*If you have performance problems here, you should not use streams in the first place*”.

Comment: @TagirValeev thank you very much! It works, I need last help, I have to sort keyset from that map, I need to add to my code something like this: `map.keySet().stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));`. It works but I don't know how to add that sorting to map, to whole program, not to only that line.

Comment: @Holger, for sorting letters in the words - yes, I'm serious. For groupingBy, etc. streams are surely fine.

Comment: @Khalos, you can just collect into the `TreeMap` which will sort automatically. Just use instead four-arguments `toMap` collector.

Comment: @TagirValeev is that possible? Im working only on values: `map.values().stream()`, can I add there argument to `toMap` which would be sorting keyset?

Comment: @Khalos: There is never a need for a `(o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2)` comparator. In case of Streams, just use `sorted()` without parameter to sort comparable values like numbers or strings. For APIs where a comparator is required, you can still use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` for them (though most APIs also support `null` to express the same).

Comment: @Holger hmmm... so I add that line `sorted()` to my code: ... map = ... and anything happen, keys are not sorted.

Comment: @Khalos: when you collect into a `Map`, the map implementation determined the order. Tagir already addressed that point in a comment. If you collect into a `TreeMap`, it will be sorted regardless of whether or how you sort before that. I only added that *if* you have a need to sort a stream, e.g. when collecting into a list afterwards, you don’t need a `(o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2)` comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```
//---------------Anagram---------------------------------
    String w1 = "Triangle".toLowerCase(), w2 = "Integral".toLowerCase();
    HashMap<String, Integer> w1Map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> w2Map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    w1Map = convertToHashMap(w1);
    w2Map = convertToHashMap(w2);       

   if( !(w1.equals(w2)) && (w1Map.keySet().equals(w2Map.keySet()))) 
       System.out.println(w1+" and "+w2+" are anagrams");
   else 
       System.out.println(w1+" and "+w2+" are not anagrams");
```

calls below method

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> convertToHashMap(String s) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0;i < s.length(); i++){
        wordMap.put(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)), Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    }
    return wordMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestAnagram {

    @Test
    public void testAnagram1() {
        String[] anagram = {"listen", "silent"};
        int v = anagram[0].toLowerCase().chars().reduce((i, j) -> i + j).getAsInt() - anagram[1].toLowerCase().chars().reduce((i, j) -> i + j).getAsInt();
        Assert.assertEquals(v, 0);

    }
}
```